# Как обработать задержку при создании компонента?

Tags: reactjs

Пишу на ReactJS. В интерфейсе есть чарты, которые генерируются динамически. Процедура такая: пользователь выбирает итем в дропдауне, по айди итема идет запрос на api, чтобы получить объект с данными для чартов. При этом в редюссере, пока данные не пришли я выставляю флаг isLoading: true. Когда данные приходят меняю на false. По этому полю я выставляю спиннер. Однако пробелма в том,что данных много и после их прихода перед рендерингом чартов проходит еще какое-то время и это смотрится не очень красиво. Можно ли как-то обработать данную ситуацию и показать к пример другой спиннер пока массив чартов не сформировался?

Comment: а менять  isLoading в componentDidMount не получается ?

Comment: Что если создать еще один action, который после прихода данных отрендерит их в блоке display: none, с искусственной задержкой, по прохождению которой isLoading станет false, а display - block?

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть так isLoading  в пропсах и  меняет redux